# Why is dotnet WASM so slow?

Tags: .net-core, webassembly

I'm doing some simple benchmarks, and I'm finding that .NET 7, compiled to WASM, is 16x slower than vanilla JS:

```cs
namespace Benchmark
{
    public partial class MainJS
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            watch.Start();
            Int64 x = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
                x += i;
            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms {x}");
        }
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Execution Time: 16482 ms 4999999950000000
```

While vanilla js:

```js
console.time("a")
let x = 0;
for (i=0; i<100000000; i++)
    x += i
console.timeEnd("a")
console.log(x)
```

Results in:

```
a: 1084.294921875 ms
4999999950000000
```

I'm having a hard time seeing the benefit of dotnet wasm for web apps when its runtime performance is so abysmal.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that my C# was not being ahead-of-time compiled to WASM.

I had to make sure I had

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

in my .csproj and then run

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

This ensures your C# is ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled to WASM. If you don't do this, then your C# will be compiled to an intermediate language (IL) in a .DLL file. The browser then downloads the .DLL file and passes it to the .NET runtime inside the WASM runtime (which is orders of magnitude slower since you are basically running a VM inside a VM).

Comment: What was the time after using AOT compared to JS?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but it was in the same order of magnitude as JavaScript at least. IIRC it was around 1500ms - it was slower than JS but not terrible

Comment: Hey, thanks to this info, my WebAssembly (wasm) executes 6X as fast.